# Mysql stored procedure error

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to add the following stored procedure to my mysql database:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE logmsg ( _Username VARCHAR(50), _Message VARCHAR(80) )
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO chatlogs (sender, message) VALUES (_Username, _Message);
END;
```

But its failing the query and returning:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3
```

I've been searching for about 2 hours on google and cannot find any answer at all.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I'm not 100% sure because I can't test on a MySQL server at the moment, I think the problem is in the semicolon. On the line with `INSERT` you basically end the `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement, which has incorrect syntax this way. You have to set the delimiter to something else (e.g. `//`), to be able to use the semicolon in the body of the procedure:

```
delimiter //

CREATE PROCEDURE logmsg ( _Username VARCHAR(50), _Message VARCHAR(80) )
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO chatlogs (sender, message) VALUES (_Username, _Message);
END//

delimiter ;
```