# MySQL 5.6.21 Stored procedure SQL error 1064

Tags: mysql, sql, database, stored-procedures

I have this query which works fine and giving the expected result.

```
SELECT count(*) AS total_unsolved,
    (select count(deadline) from my_table where datediff(deadline, CURTIME()) = 0 and response_time is null) as today_to_solve,
    (select count(deadline) from my_table where datediff(deadline, CURTIME()) > 0 and datediff(deadline, CURTIME()) < 4 and response_time is null) as days_left_1_3,
    (select count(deadline) from my_table where datediff(deadline, CURTIME()) > 3 and datediff(deadline, CURTIME()) < 8 and response_time is null) as days_left_4_7,
    (select count(deadline) from my_table where datediff(deadline, CURTIME()) > 7 and response_time is null) as mt_week,
    (select count(deadline) from my_table where datediff(deadline, CURTIME()) < 0 and datediff(deadline, CURTIME()) > -4 and response_time is null) as overdue_1_3_days,
    (select count(deadline) from my_table where datediff(deadline, CURTIME()) < -3 and datediff(deadline, CURTIME()) > -11 and response_time is null) as overdue_4_10_days,
    (select count(deadline) from my_table where datediff(deadline, CURTIME()) < -10 and datediff(deadline, CURTIME()) > -30 and response_time is null) as overdue_11_30_days,
    (select count(deadline) from my_table where datediff(deadline, CURTIME()) < -30 and response_time is null) as overdue_mt_month,
    (select count(deadline) from my_table where datediff(deadline, response_time) < 0 and response_time is not null) as solved_with_delay  
 from my_table where response_time is null
```

[image]

I would like to create a procedure that shows the result in a given time range.
So I typed the following:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE status_in_timerange
     (
        IN   start_date                     TiMESTAMP, 
        IN   close_date                     TiMESTAMP,
        OUT  total_unsolved                 INT,  
        OUT  today_to_solve                 INT, 
        OUT  days_left_1_3                  INT, 
        OUT  days_left_4_7                  INT, 
        OUT  mt_week                        INT, 
        OUT  overdue_1_3_days               INT, 
        OUT  overdue_4_10_days              INT,      
        OUT  overdue_11_30_days             INT,    
        OUT  overdue_mt_month               INT,    
        OUT  solved_with_delay              INT    
     )
BEGIN 

    SELECT count(DATEDIFF(deadline, NOW())) AS total_unsolved,
        (select count(deadline) from my_table where datediff(deadline, CURTIME()) = 0 and response_time is null and ktimestamp BETWEEN start_date and close_date),
        (select count(deadline) from my_table where datediff(deadline, CURTIME()) > 0 and datediff(deadline, CURTIME()) < 4 and response_time is null and ktimestamp BETWEEN start_date and close_date),
        (select count(deadline) from my_table where datediff(deadline, CURTIME()) > 3 and datediff(deadline, CURTIME()) < 8 and response_time is null and ktimestamp BETWEEN start_date and close_date),
        (select count(deadline) from my_table where datediff(deadline, CURTIME()) > 7 and response_time is null and ktimestamp BETWEEN start_date and close_date),
        (select count(deadline) from my_table where datediff(deadline, CURTIME()) < 0 and datediff(deadline, CURTIME()) > -4 and response_time is null and ktimestamp BETWEEN start_date and close_date),
        (select count(deadline) from my_table where datediff(deadline, CURTIME()) < -3 and datediff(deadline, CURTIME()) > -11 and response_time is null and ktimestamp BETWEEN start_date and close_date),
        (select count(deadline) from my_table where datediff(deadline, CURTIME()) < -10 and datediff(deadline, CURTIME()) > -30 and response_time is null and ktimestamp BETWEEN start_date and close_date),
        (select count(deadline) from my_table where datediff(deadline, CURTIME()) < -30 and response_time is null and ktimestamp BETWEEN start_date and close_date),
        (select count(deadline) from my_table where datediff(deadline, response_time) < 0 and response_time is not null and ktimestamp BETWEEN start_date and close_date) 

    INTO   total_unsolved , 
           today_to_solve, 
           days_left_1_3, 
           days_left_4_7, 
           mt_week, 
           overdue_1_3_days ,
           overdue_4_10_days,
           overdue_11_30_days,
           overdue_mt_month,
           solved_with_delay

  FROM my_table WHERE response_time is null and ktimestamp BETWEEN start_date and close_date
END ;
```

Unfortunately, this query is showing an error as below:

> SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'END' at line 41

I have read related questions (including the following) which didn't help to solve the issue.

[Mysql stored procedure error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698495/mysql-stored-procedure-error)

[Mysql stored procedure error 1064](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11816434/mysql-stored-procedure-error-1064)

P.S. `select version();` returns 5.6.21

Comment: Please help me out to find the mistake from the stored procedure

Comment: Have a look into http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/database-troubleshooting/error-1064

Comment: Add a semicolon (`;`) at the end of the statement: `... WHERE response_time is null and ktimestamp BETWEEN start_date and close_date;`.

Comment: @sForSujit I have gone through that article and video which explained common cases with Error 1064. But I couldn't find any of these mistakes in my stored procedure. If you could see any, please give me a hint

Comment: @wchiquito using delimiter at that point caused new error at the line: SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near " at line 40

Comment: Can you tell us which is line 41 in your code?

Comment: @sForSujit the last line

Comment: Did you try what @wchiquito said, ?

Comment: Yes, Thank you for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```sql
mysql> DELIMITER //

mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE status_in_timerange
    ->      (
    ->         IN   start_date                     TiMESTAMP, 
    ->         IN   close_date                     TiMESTAMP,
    ->         OUT  total_unsolved                 INT,  
    ->         OUT  today_to_solve                 INT, 
    ->         OUT  days_left_1_3                  INT, 
    ->         OUT  days_left_4_7                  INT, 
    ->         OUT  mt_week                        INT, 
    ->         OUT  overdue_1_3_days               INT, 
    ->         OUT  overdue_4_10_days              INT,      
    ->         OUT  overdue_11_30_days             INT,    
    ->         OUT  overdue_mt_month               INT,    
    ->         OUT  solved_with_delay              INT    
    ->      )
    -> BEGIN 
    ->     SELECT count(DATEDIFF(deadline, NOW())) AS total_unsolved,
    ->         (select count(deadline) from my_table where datediff(deadline, CURTIME()) = 0 and response_time is null and ktimestamp BETWEEN start_date and close_date),
    ->         (select count(deadline) from my_table where datediff(deadline, CURTIME()) > 0 and datediff(deadline, CURTIME()) < 4 and response_time is null and ktimestamp BETWEEN start_date and close_date),
    ->         (select count(deadline) from my_table where datediff(deadline, CURTIME()) > 3 and datediff(deadline, CURTIME()) < 8 and response_time is null and ktimestamp BETWEEN start_date and close_date),
    ->         (select count(deadline) from my_table where datediff(deadline, CURTIME()) > 7 and response_time is null and ktimestamp BETWEEN start_date and close_date),
    ->         (select count(deadline) from my_table where datediff(deadline, CURTIME()) < 0 and datediff(deadline, CURTIME()) > -4 and response_time is null and ktimestamp BETWEEN start_date and close_date),
    ->         (select count(deadline) from my_table where datediff(deadline, CURTIME()) < -3 and datediff(deadline, CURTIME()) > -11 and response_time is null and ktimestamp BETWEEN start_date and close_date),
    ->         (select count(deadline) from my_table where datediff(deadline, CURTIME()) < -10 and datediff(deadline, CURTIME()) > -30 and response_time is null and ktimestamp BETWEEN start_date and close_date),
    ->         (select count(deadline) from my_table where datediff(deadline, CURTIME()) < -30 and response_time is null and ktimestamp BETWEEN start_date and close_date),
    ->         (select count(deadline) from my_table where datediff(deadline, response_time) < 0 and response_time is not null and ktimestamp BETWEEN start_date and close_date) 
    ->     INTO   total_unsolved , 
    ->            today_to_solve, 
    ->            days_left_1_3, 
    ->            days_left_4_7, 
    ->            mt_week, 
    ->            overdue_1_3_days ,
    ->            overdue_4_10_days,
    ->            overdue_11_30_days,
    ->            overdue_mt_month,
    ->            solved_with_delay
    ->   FROM my_table
    ->   WHERE response_time is null and
    ->         ktimestamp BETWEEN start_date and close_date;
    -> END//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER ;
```